# How does jQuery affect CSS structure

Tags: jquery, css

Just re-entering heavy duty js and CSS world after a couple years working only in Flash and coming up to speed on jQuery. I'm designing some CSS/DIV-based layouts and will be depending on jQuery and AJAX for interactions.

As regards the CSS coding conventions and structure, how can I design SS to best take advantage of jQuery?

What CSS concepts should I be mastering if I want my jQuery design work to dovetail with the CSS work?

thx
--steve...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's some [jQuery performance rules](http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/) that gives some tips on how to set up ids and classes.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at the [jQuery UI CSS](http://jqueryui.pbworks.com/jQuery-UI-CSS-Framework) Framework. It's a clever and jQuery-friendly way of styling your UI. Pretty neat stuff...

Comment: Going with that framework makes a great deal of sense. i'm creating Views for a .NET MVC project and i'm seeing others are foregoing MS's ajax. Still not as well defined route - it's not as widely tutorialized. Which is what's prompting this question in the first place. thx!

Answer (score 1):

Basic rule to take advantage of CSS w.r.t. jQuery: use classes. and then use more classes. but make sure classes represent "role", not "behaviour"

eg: this is bad

```
<ul>
   <li class='red'><a href='http://microsoft.com/'>MS</a></li>
   <li><a href='http://google.com/'>goog</a></li>
   <li class='green-bg'><a href=http://ubuntu.com/'>Ubuntu</a></li>
</ul>
```

eg: this is good.

```
<ul>
   <li class='bad-link'><a href='http://microsoft.com/'>MS</a></li>
   <li><a href='http://google.com/'>goog</a></li>
   <li class='current-link'><a href=http://ubuntu.com/'>Ubuntu</a></li>
</ul>
```

This subtle CSS convention will allow you to do powerful things to your UI with real ease.

Cheers, jrh.

Comment: Appreciate seeing this depicted. It appears as the primary point delivered in Emily's list <wonders if _that nic's on purpose> ;)